# What's the difference in pronunciation between kuàir and kuàr?

Tags: pronunciation, erhuayin

- [块儿](http://youdao.com/w/%E5%9D%97%E5%84%BF) (kuàir) = a slice, etc.
- [跨儿](https://www.baidu.com/s?wd=%E8%B7%A8%E5%84%BF) (kuàr) = "trans", in the sense of "transgender".

Reading these aloud, I don't notice a distinction in pronunciation, but it seems like there should be.

**Question**: What's the difference in pronunciation between kuàir and kuàr?

Comment: I guess the main difference is actually in the context, they pronounce the same but not really used in the same kind of sentences

Comment: Are you sure 跨儿 is pronounced "kuar"? 块儿 would indeed merge the two pronunciations as a sort of colloquialism into "kuair" (same as 块 on its own but with a rolling tongue at the end), but I thought 跨儿 might be pronounced separately "kua'er".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have the same pronunciation.

The wiki page on [Erhua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erhua#Rules_in_Standard_Mandarin) lists the IPA of both finals ("uar" and "uair") to be [wɐʵ]

Answer (score 0):

When you pronounce the two terms with an 儿, they sound the same.

The difference in pinyin is due to the original word without 儿.

块：kuài
跨：kuà

Comment: Funny, with or without the 儿, the words sound different enough to distinguish. 块 has a tail-lift, while 跨 is flat all the way.